# css absolute div with svg streches whole page

Tags: html, css, svg

I'm developing a site where there is a need to use a large svg shape under the whole site.

```css
#blobunder {
    position: absolute;
    display: inline-table;
    width: 100vw;
    z-index: -1;
    overflow: hidden;
    height: 100vh;
    max-height: 100vh;
}

#blobunder svg {
    position: relative;
    // transform:translate(0px, 500px); - optional
    width: 150vw;
    text-align: center;
}

body {
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html <?php language_attributes(); ?> class="is-fullheight">
<head>
    <meta charset="<?php bloginfo( 'charset' ); ?>">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="profile" href="http://gmpg.org/xfn/11">
    <?php wp_head(); ?>
</head>

<body <?php body_class(); ?> >

<div id="page" class="site">
    <div id="blobunder">
        <div id="blobunderinside">
            <svg version="1.1" id="Layer_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px" viewBox="0 0 110 100" enable-background="new 0 0 110 100" xml:space="preserve">
                <path fill="#f6f6f6" d="M60.928,3.635c2.338-0.121,4.393,0.927,6.416,1.805c11.501,5.003,21.997,11.687,31.823,19.44
                    c1.45,1.146,2.773,2.477,4.018,3.847c2.505,2.762,3.349,5.852,2.292,9.626c-1.043,3.738-2.307,7.386-3.901,10.879
                    c-5.939,13.016-12.549,25.684-20.454,37.627c-3.471,5.245-7.8,9.173-14.501,10.301c-2.482,0.417-4.452-0.264-6.524-0.682
                    c-16.783-3.404-33.143-8.026-48.479-15.995c-6.936-3.603-9.595-9.991-7.715-17.854c2.66-11.129,6.395-21.829,10.812-32.319
                    c2.278-5.41,5.827-9.832,11.236-12.582c10.17-5.175,20.441-10.086,31.393-13.448C58.549,3.91,59.689,3.618,60.928,3.635z"/>
            </svg>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

And the problem I'm looking to solve is that this svg section stretches height of the whole page and svg shape sticks down below the actual end of the page - so it's visibly under footer section. Overflow doesn't do the trick. Did anyone had similar issue? What I want to do is to make the shape bigger than page's content and cut it where the page actually ends.

Comment: Since you haven't included any of the SVG code and thereby omitted the viewport etc it's hard to help you here. I would guess you could use the svg as a background image and do it that way tho...

Comment: here you go - I added the whole header and svg - hope that's clearer now

Comment: @Mech What do you mean by `Should class be in an html tag?`?

Comment: Why would a class in the HTML tag be confusing? It's irrelevant for this questions but I'm not following what you mean?

Comment: <html class="is-fullheight"> or <html> - it's not it - it doesn't affect the issue. It's a class automaticaly added by worpdress boilerplate template I'm using

Comment: @Mech <body <?php body_class(); ?> > - this is correct the extra > is body closing tag, the one before closes php

Comment: Hi @AndrzejDzirba, it seems to be behaving for me as I would expect. The SVG is overflowing over the page's body and being hidden - it isn't causing the webpage to be scrollable.

Of course the more we have to work with, the more we can help. I don't suppose you have a live site at the moment that we can view with this problem on it, do you?

Comment: @Michael Thompson - thank you for reply. You managing to make it work probably means that some other styles on the site create this unusual behavior. Unfortunately I can't seems to find it at all - and that's been bugging me as my goal is rather simple. In the meanwhile, I managed to use a little trick - the svg is now introduced as a body's background - which works to the extend of cutting the image where the page ends, but as I wanted to do some animation and manipulation on the svg, it's probably just a temp solution. To answer your question - I don't have any published code with that.